# Eclipse compatibility on Windows 8

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, java

I am planning to upgrade my PC to Windows 8, but I have some concerns regarding the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) compatibility.

1. Especially regarding Android development in Eclipse
2. Qualcomm [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) for augmented reality compatibility ([Vuforia](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality))

Does work Eclipse for these specific tasks on Windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Eclipse with the ADK since the Windows 8 consumer preview. To-date I've never had an issue with the IDE and working on the Android platform.

Windows 8 by default supports Windows 7 "desktop" application, which includes Java and any additions so there should also be no issue with the Qualcomm SDKs - but I haven't personally tested them.